# Specify to which mysites search center links to

Tags: 2010, search, my-site, search-results

On an SP2010 farm, I've got two mysites. One has its own webapp, let's call it MySites1, and another one, MySites2 resides in the same webapp where the enterprise search center is.

The User Profile Service is configured to use the enterprise search center. Searching from MySites2 works properly. However the results link to MySites1 and not MySites2. MySites1 is inaccessible due to various reasons, and I also can't simply remove it.

Basically, I'd like to change the search center, so that that the results link to MySites2, without removing MySites1. How can I do that if that's possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure the My Sites in the User Profile Service Application to point to your MySites2.  The search center is using which ever My Sites are configured in the UPA.